# Using base class and base interface in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I am reshaping an entire system that does not use base classes and base interfaces.

My idea to do so is to extract all the common methods to a base classes and base interfaces.
So basically, we would have:

- A base class `SomeClassBase` implementing an interface `ISomeClassBase`
- A derived class SomeClassDerived implementing `ISomeClassDerived` (this interface deriving from `ISomeClassBase`)

Now the problem, how can I instantiate "_mySession" in the derived class (which has a different cast than in the base class), while preserving all the methods from the base class:

```
public class SomeClassBase : ISomeClassBase 
{
 public IMySessionBase _mySession = MySession.Instance();

 public SomeClassBase ()
 {
   _mySession.connect();  // Needed??
 }

 public void doSomething()
 {
  _mySession.doSomething();
 }
}

public class SomeClassDerived : SomeClassBase, ISomeClassDerived  
{
 public IMySessionDerived _mySession = MySession.Instance();

 public SomeClassDerived ()
 {
  _mySession.connect();
 }

 public void doSomethingElse()
 {    
  _mySession.doSomethingElse();
 }
}
```

One more thing, `IMySessionDerived` implements `IMySessionBase`.

Comment: but there is no hierarchy connection between `SomeClassBase` and `SomeClassDerived` (well they both implement `ISomeClassBase` but independently) so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the instantiation of _mySession. If I create a new instance of the derived class. I am not sure a constructor should be in the base class. Or should it? Will _mySession from the base class be the same recasted one in the derived class?

Comment: *"recasted"* ? *base class* ? again ... there is no connection between `SomeClassBase`  and `SomeClassDerived`

Comment: _mySession has the cast "IMySessionBase " in the base class, but IMySessionDerived in the derived class.

Comment: *`class SomeClassBase : ISomeClassBase` `class SomeClassDerived : ISomeClassDerived`* again `SomeClassDerived` in your code is not derived from `SomeClassBase`

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, just edited the code: _SomeClassDerived_ derives from _SomeClassBase_

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jiIY35

Comment: Not sure what to make of this. How is this a better solution from the one provided by @"Code Name Jack" ? Is this better practice?

Comment: and where in his solution `SomeClassDerived` implements `doSomething` ?

Comment: At construction when calling: __baseClassInstance=new SomeClassBase(_mySession);_

Comment: *and where in his solution SomeClassDerived implements doSomething* .. *At construction when calling: _baseClassInstance=new SomeClassBase(_mySession);* ... yeah, hehehehe,  that's what we call implementing method (oh wait ... it's look like creating instance and assign)... Ok, sorry, I have to give up - we are talking in different languages  ... stick with his method ...

Comment: Sorry to have offended you, I don't see what you see obviously!

Comment: Your example is neat, I will follow that. I just don't get what is wrong with the other one, but I will interpret from your unfriendly wording that you have something very precise in mind (ie. An understanding I do not have - Which is why I created this thread in the first place). So I will assume your solution is the best of the 2. I would have just hoped to get more of a tutorial from this forum rather than a: "You are too dumb to get it" kind of answer!

Comment: It was more like "you didn't clear explain what you want, and I have no time for guessing"

Comment: Ok, I had the feeling you both understood well, but just gave different ways to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting @Selvin answer instead of the link buried in the comments:
The trick here is to use the keyword "base()"

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var o1 = new O1();
        o1.DS1();
        var o2 = new O2();
        o2.DS1();
        o2.DS2();
    }

    public class Session1
    {
        protected readonly Type ownerType;
        public Session1(Type type)
        {
            ownerType = type;
        }

        public virtual void DS1([CallerMemberName] string functionName = "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ownerType.Name + ":" +  GetType().Name + ":" + functionName);
        }       
    }

    public class Session2 : Session1
    {
        public Session2(Type type):base(type) { }

        public virtual void DS2([CallerMemberName] string functionName = "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ownerType.Name + ":" +  GetType().Name + ":" + functionName);
        }   
    }

    public class O1
    {
        private readonly Session1 t;

        public O1() : this(new Session1(typeof(O1))) { }
        protected O1(Session1 t)
        {
            this.t = t;
        }
        public void DS1()
        {
            t.DS1();
        }
    }

    public class O2 : O1
    {
        private readonly Session2 t;

        public O2() : this(new Session2(typeof(O2))) { }
        protected O2(Session2 t) : base(t)
        {
            this.t = t;
        }

        public void DS2()
        {
            t.DS2();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not redefine `_mySession` Let it come from base class.
However in you Derived class you can still reassign.

```
public class SomeClassDerived : SomeClassBase, ISomeClassDerived  
{
 public SomeClassDerived ()
 {
  _mySession = MySession.Instance(); //Declaration comes from base class automatically
  _mySession.connect();
 }

 public void doSomethingElse()
 {    
  _mySession.doSomethingElse();
 }
}
```

If your `IMySessionBase` and `IMySessionDerived` are following Hierarchy, it should work. But in some rare cases, You might end up getting into a DoubleDispatchProblem.

As Pointed out in commens, If you want to do something from `IMySessionDerived` you can add a Property.

```
public class SomeClassDerived : SomeClassBase, ISomeClassDerived  
{
    IMySessionDerived _derivedSessionAccessor=>  _mySession as IMySessionDerived;

}
```

**Update: To fix the exact design problem here,**

Instead of deriving from the base class, have it as a field. And inherit from interface. So Instead of doing above approach,

do like,

```
public class SomeClassBase : ISomeClassBase 
{
 public IMySessionBase _mySession ;
 public SomeClassBase ( IMySessionBase session)
 {
   _mySession=session;
   _mySession.connect();  // Needed??
 }

 public void doSomething()
 {
  _mySession.doSomething();
 }
}

 public class SomeClassDerived : , ISomeClassDerived  
{
 public IMySessionDerived _mySession = MySession.Instance();
 private SomeClassBase _baseClassInstance;
 public SomeClassDerived ()
 {
   _baseClassInstance=new SomeClassBase(_mySession);
    //_mySession.connect();
 }

 public void doSomethingElse()
 {    
  _baseClassInstance.doSomethingElse();
 }
}
```

Comment: but you can't call `_mySession.doSomethingElse();` if `doSomethingElse` is from `IMySessionDerived` and nor `IMySessionBase`

Comment: Yes, True that, But you can typecast it in the derived class. This whole design is a violation of Liskov Substitution principle. But still it suits OPs scenario.

Comment: @Selvin, you are right and this is the exact problem I am trying to solve!

Comment: @Code Name Jack, are you saying this is a bad approach? How would you design it then?

Comment: In these cases, Prefer Composition over Inheritence, Implement the interface but don't inherit from baseclass, I will add it in my answer

Comment: Ok, so _doSomethingElse_ would then call __derivedSessionAccessor.doSomethingElse()_ instead of __mySession.doSomethingElse()_, correct?

Comment: yes, but not  _derivedSessionAccessor.doSomethingElse() , it should be _baseSessionAccessor.doSomethingElse()

Comment: Is your answer a good approach though or just a work around to solve my problem? Is that something you would rather do or avoid?
Still not getting why my question keeps on being downgraded!?

Comment: so you are creating `SomeClassBase` instance inside `SomeClassDerived`  instead extending it? so now you are proxing two classes ...

Comment: Not sure how extensions could help here. Would you mind sharing what you have in mind?

Comment: I am using two classes here and at the same time removed it from the base class. Remember "If It looks like duck, talks like duck, but it uses battery, then it is not a duck". Avoid inheritance in slightest doubt.
 @toughQuestions from whatever is clear from your question, It should be the right approach. Infact, remove the base class, use the session directly wherever needed is the best approach. Because in most of the cases you will not get any benefit until your session has some long tasks.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Would you say that the answer from @Selvin is overkill then? cf. [link](http://dotnetfiddle.net/jiIY35)

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why my answer has been downvoted.

Comment: Me neither, your answers were very helpful! Don't get why my question was downvoted so badly either. Thought we were having a pretty smooth discussion about it.

Comment: Yes, please up vote and mark it as answer if it has helped you